# Copy a list of files with Spark from HDFS to HDFS

Tags: java, apache-spark, copy, hdfs

I have a file like this:

```
/root/dir1/file1
/root/dir2/subdir/file2
...
```

And I need to copy those files on another location using java Spark like this

```
/dest/dir1/file1
/dest/dir2/subdir/file2
...
```

So basically I need to replace the begining of each path by the destination root.
For a single file I could do:

```
sc.textFile("/root/dir1/file1").saveAsTextFile("/dest/dir1/file1")
```

But I really have no clue how to deal with a list of files in a distributed fashion, renaming path etc...

Any help ?